# How can I create a two-dimensional dynamic array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I define a two-dimensional dynamic array? I'm writing Dijkstra algorithm program, I want each node that is connected to another node to save its value into an array. In fact, it should be a dynamic, two-dimensional array. Not specified which one of nodes connected to another nodes.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a `List<List<T>>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a little while since I've done a Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation but you can represent your data in a few ways. You can have a list of lists, for example, or an array of lists. You could then treat the array index as the vertex label and the list as the list of arrays that it's connected to.

```
public class Node
{
   public int Weight { get; set; }
   public int Connected { get; set; }
}

// You can use either an array of lists or a list of lists
List<List<Node>> graph = new List<List<Node>>();
        // The index is the edge label - e.g. arr[0] is the edge labeled "0"
        graph[0] = new List<Node>()
        {
            new Node() { Weight = 175, Connected = 1 },
            new Node() { Weight= 100, Connected = 2 }
            // Etc...
        };
        graph[1] = new List<Node>()
        {
            // Basically, to represent an undirected edge you're representing two weighted edges
            // (i.e. a connection from 1 -> 2 and a connection from 2 -> 1)
            // This also makes directed edges easy to represent
            new Node() { Weight = 175, Connected = 1 }
            // Etc...
        };
```

You can also, for example, have a list (or set) of vertices and a list of edges. (In fact, in the formal mathematical sense, that is the actual definition of a graph - a set of edges and a set of vertices).

Comment: Thanks so much for answer , but not specified the number of nodes may the number of nodes 7 or 100 or 1000.i mean this is code : List<Node>[] arr = new List<Node>[7];

Comment: Yes, you can either do a List of Lists, a List of Arrays, or an Array of Lists (depending on how much information you have in advance). You can also allocate the size of the arrays at runtime if that's what you're looking to do. In your case (since you specified that they should be dynamic) you'll probably want to do a List of Lists. The code is actually more or less the same using a List of Lists (you can still do indices and whatnot).

Comment: i don't know size of my data at runtime.because it nodes may Gradually increasing for example : at first nodes may there are 2 ,..5 or 6,... and then connected to another nodes i decide new nodes add.

Comment: In that case you'll definitely want to go with a List of Lists rather than an array. I edited my answer to use purely that (rather than arrays).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a dynamic array the use List<> object.  I hard coded values but you can use the Add() method when you need a dynamic object

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Node> graph = new List<Node>() {
                new Node() { 
                    id = 0, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 1,127),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,100),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 4,139),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 6,117),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 7,156)
                    }
                },
                new Node() { 
                    id = 1, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,127),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,102),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 3,108),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 7,53)
                    }
                },
                new Node() { 
                    id = 2, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,100),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 1,102),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 3,111),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 4,173),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 5,175)
                    }
                },            
                new Node() { 
                    id = 3, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 1,108),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,111)
                    }
                },            
                new Node() { 
                    id = 4, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,139),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,173),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 6,165)
                    }
                },            
                new Node() { 
                    id = 5, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 2,175),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 6,95),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 7,145)
                    }
                },            
                new Node() { 
                    id = 6, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,117),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 4,165),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 5,95)
                    }
                },            
                new Node() { 
                    id = 7, neighbors = new List<KeyValuePair<int,int>>() {
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 0,156),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 1,53),
                       new KeyValuePair<int,int>( 5,145)
                    }
                }            
            };
        }
    }
    public class Node
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> neighbors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use [][]:

```
double[][] x = new double[5][];

x[0] = new double[10];
x[1] = new double[5];
x[2] = new double[3];
x[3] = new double[100];
x[4] = new double[1];
```

The second option is to use:

```
List<List<double>> 2darray = new List<List<double>> ();
2darray[0] = new List<double>();
2darray[0][0] = 1;
```

Comment: Double won't work here - you need to be able to store both the edge weight and the edge that you're connecting to. Also, you can't use an array of arrays because its size is allocated statically (the question asked how to do this dynamically).